# RxJs Timer Reset on Event

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

**Some context:** I have an application built in Angular 6 that has an interactive dashboard with data that updates every 60 sec using an RxJS interval

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.poller = this.getDataPoller().subscribe(data => {
    // update the dashboard charts
  });
}

getDataPoller() {
  return interval(60000)
    .pipe(
      startWith(0),
      switchMap(() => this.http.get(url))
    );
}
```

Users are able to interact with the dashboard by drilling down into pie charts etc, but every time the data is refreshed, the dashboard charts are redrawn. I would like to keep this functionality so that when no activity occurs after some the charts get redrawn

But while the user is interacting (i.e. click events) with the charts, I would like the timer to get reset with each click so that no data is fetched until 60s after the last click event.

I thought using a debounce would be the way to go, but I couldn't get it working properly and with each click event, it fetched new data immediately.

I've started a [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rxjs-interval-debounce) if anyone could please shed some light.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter is your friend. Have a property lastInteraction on the component that gets set to the current time on each interaction.

```
this.lastInteraction = new Date();
```

and in the pipe of your getDataPoller filter based on a defined inactivity period passed or not

```
startWith(0),
filter(() => (new Date().getTime() - this.lastInteraction.getTime()) > this.definedInactivityPeriod)
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rxjs-interval-debounce-cfw6at

Comment: Didn't event think of filter. Thanks very much, works great